# X11 application losing focus after 1-2 secs

Tags: macos, mac, xorg, window-focus

I'm using Mac **OS X 10.6.5** and I'm trying to run some applications on **X11 2.3.6**.
Any application I run, xterm included, loses focus after 1-2 seconds, making them impossible to use.

I'm running various programmes downloaded from fink, and they all do the same, which exludes an application-specific bug.
I tried all the options available (follow focus, clickthrough, etc) in X11 with no success.

I couldn't find a fix for this issue.
Any ideas?

EDIT: I also posted this question at:
http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2655263&stqc=true

EDIT: the issue doesn't arise if I close all the other applications and I leave open only X11. It's not ideal but it works for the moment.

Comment: do you use multiple screens or spaces? The window can be hidden in another screen/space.

Comment: yes I use the spaces. I just tried after disabling the spaces, and nothing changes. I open just one app under x11, and it loses focus for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue doesn't arise if I close all the other applications and I leave open only X11. It's not ideal but it works for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this, and the reason was super silly: it was because of stuff I put on top of my wireless touchpad (Apple's "Magic Trackpad").

It took me hours and hours to figure this out. I spent 1 hour with someone from Apple on the phone trying to trouble shoot the problem. Rebooted my machine N times, tried another mouse, taking out all USB devices, all sorts of things. In the end, I realized (by chance) that a folder was sitting on top of the touchpad (which I hadn't used for days), and that's what was confusing it and causing the focus issues...

Comment: that's a good one ;-) But unfortunately in my case it must be a software issue. All the other apps work perfectly, it's just an issue with X11.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. The solution for me was in the apple discussion post, about removing a lyrics applet from my dashboard. The problem was only occurring for me after I had opened the dashboard since loggin on to the computer.